# How to use Zend Dom Query without Zend FW?

Tags: php, zend-framework, dom

Is it possible to use Zend Dom Query without Zend Framework?

If yes: Where to download Zend Dom Query and how to use it without Zend Framework?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pull out the separate ZF files using some package managers like [this one](http://epic.codeutopia.net/pack/library/1.10.6), which will tell what files do you need and will compress them for you. Zend_Dom_Query requires only

- Zend/Dom/Query.php
- Zend/Dom/Query/Css2Xpath.php
- Zend/Dom/Query/Result.php
- Zend/Dom/Exception.php
- Zend/Exception.php

Anyhow, it's available [for download](https://github.com/jhartikainen/packageizer). If there is an urgent need - there are lot of other tools like this one not only for ZF.

Comment: Unless you have issues with disk space I wouldn't bother with this step, just download the minimal library version and put it on your include path.

Comment: sure, but when you're developing some custom module for some custom CMS and don't want your installation package grow in megabytes - why not using such tools?

Answer (score 1):

The classes in Zend are not meant to be used standalone - is there a reason you cannot have the whole of ZF available but only use Zend_Dom_Query?

Failing that you can get the folder

> /library/Dom/

And take it out of the ZF folder, you'll then need to look for any depenancies, having a quick look you will also need:

> /library/Exception/Exception.php

Give that a go, let us know how it goes....

Answer (score 1):

I assume by 'without Zend Framework' you mean without using Zend Framework's MVC components. You can use any component of Zend Framework in isolation; it is a glue framework.

Download the library and extract it into your project's library folder or PHP include path. It should then be roughly as simple as the following:

```
<?php
require_once 'Zend/Dom/Query.php';

$query = new Zend_Dom_Query(....);
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me this approach doesn't work with Zend Framework 2, I don't know why...

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**`zendframework/zend-dom`**](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-dom) as a standalone component. It has no external dependencies, which means that it doesn't need another Zend component or other library to work.

Alternatively, you could also use a library that is totally unrelated to Zend, like [**`tburry/pquery`**](https://github.com/tburry/pquery) or my own [**`PHPPowertools/DOM-Query`**](https://github.com/PHPPowertools/DOM-Query). Both libraries serve the same purpose as [**`zendframework/zend-dom`**](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-dom), but syntax is different and HTML5 support may vary for each library.

**Example :**

This example illustrates how you'd load an HTML string and query for `.foo .bar a`, with each of these three libraries :

Using [**`zendframework/zend-dom`**](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-dom) you'd do this :

```
use \Zend\Dom\Query;

$dom = new Query($htmlcode);
$results = $dom->execute('.foo .bar a');
```

Using [**`tburry/pquery`**](https://github.com/tburry/pquery), you'd do this :

```
use \pQuery\pQuery

$dom = pQuery::parseStr($htmlcode);
$dom->query('.foo .bar a');
```

Using [**`PHPPowertools/DOM-Query`**](https://github.com/PHPPowertools/DOM-Query), you'd do this :

```
use \PowerTools\DOM_Query

$H = new DOM_Query($htmlcode);
$s = $H->select('.foo .bar a');
```

Pick your poison!